# How to unset nested property in `beforeSave` cloud function?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

I've extended a `Parse.Object`. Now I want to unset a nested property before saving an object. This nested property `settings` is an object.

So my hook looks like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('MyObject', req => {
   if (req.object.get('settings').propertyToUnset) {
       req.object.unset('settings.propertyToUnset');
   }
});
```

However, that produces the error `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

How does `unset` work for nested properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the plain JavaScript command `delete` to delete a property of nested object `settings`:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('MyObject', req => {
    if (req.object.get('settings').propertyToUnset) {
        delete req.object.get('settings').propertyToUnset;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('MyObject', async req => {
   const settings = req.object.get('settings');
   await settings.fetch();
   if (settings.get('propertyToUnset')) {
       settings.unset('propertyToUnset');
       await settings.save();
   }
});
```

Comment: That means that nested objects are not fetched by default?

Comment: It doesn't work: "fetch is not a function". It works if I use `delete req.object.get('settings').propertyToUnset`. So there's no way in Parse to do that with `unset`?

Comment: I was supposing that `settings` were a `Pointer`. Is it an object? In this case the `delete` is the way to go.

Comment: It is an object, yes. Thanks, I'll edit that in the question.